# How to write a php code for the page title, next post, previous post with mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm an outsider for the php with MySQL.

For my below code is testing : http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/company.php?crno=1 ,

How to write a php code for the page title, next post, previous post with mySQL ?

I want to set the "com_eng_name" & "com_eng_name" to be my page title.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="rights" content="www.findoutbusiness.com" />
  <title></title>

</head>
<body >


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abc";
$password = "abc1234";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



// select data

$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM ComData WHERE com_no = '. $_GET['crno'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<b>CR No.: </b>" . $row["com_no"]. "<br>" . 
       "<b>Company English Name: </b>" . $row["com_eng_name"]. "<br>" . 
    "<b>Company Chinse Name: </b>" . $row["com_chi_name"]. "<br>" . 
     "<b>Company Type: </b>" . $row["com_type"]. "<br>" . 
    "<b>Date of Incorporation: </b>" . $row["date_of_incorp"]. "<br>" . 
             "<b>Active Status: </b>" . $row["active_status"]. "<br>" . 
             "<b>Date of Dissolution: </b>" . $row["date_of_dissolution"]. "<br>" .     
             "<b>Remarks: </b>" . $row["remark"]. " " .  
    "<br><br><br>";
   

    }
} else {
    echo "No Results";
}

$conn->close();
?>



</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help & support in advance !

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abc";
$password = "abc1234";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



// select data

$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM ComData WHERE com_no = '. $_GET['crno'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pageTitle = $row['com_eng_name'];
        $content   = "<b>CR No.: </b>" . $row["com_no"]. "<br>" . 
       "<b>Company English Name: </b>" . $row["com_eng_name"]. "<br>" . 
    "<b>Company Chinse Name: </b>" . $row["com_chi_name"]. "<br>" . 
     "<b>Company Type: </b>" . $row["com_type"]. "<br>" . 
    "<b>Date of Incorporation: </b>" . $row["date_of_incorp"]. "<br>" . 
             "<b>Active Status: </b>" . $row["active_status"]. "<br>" . 
             "<b>Date of Dissolution: </b>" . $row["date_of_dissolution"]. "<br>" .     
             "<b>Remarks: </b>" . $row["remark"]. " " .  
    "<br><br><br>";
   

    }
} else {
    echo "No Results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="rights" content="www.findoutbusiness.com" />
  <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
</head>

<body >
<?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help & support!

Comment: If I gave you the answer for your question, I rather see it accepted as answer for gaining reputation. Thx